# Combining unrelated queries into one query to produce counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like a stored procedure to run daily that produces a report of counts.

For example, the .csv would look something like this:

```
    Daily,1
    Deaths,0
    In-House EKG,4
    In-House Xray,2
    Suicidal Patients,12
    HIV,0
```

Their individual queries look something like this:

```
-- Daily and Death Counts
select
    SUM(CASE WHEN location != '[OUT]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Daily',
    SUM(CASE WHEN death = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Deaths'
from
    patient_data


-- In-House Tasks
select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cat_id = 72 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'In-House EKG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN cat_id = 73 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'In-House XRay',    
from
    organizer_tasks

-- Suicidal Patients
select 
    count(distinct(pid)) as 'Suicidal Inmates'
from 
    problems pr 
        inner join problem_list pl on pl.id = pr.problem_list_id 
where 
    pr.status = 'open'
    and pl.title like '%suicide%'

-- HIV

select 
    count(distinct(pid)) as 'HIV'
from 
    problems pr 
        inner join problem_list pl on pl.id = pr.problem_list_id 
        inner join patient_data pd on pr.pid = pd.pid
where 
    pr.status = 'open'
    and pl.title like '%hiv%'
```

As you can see, each set of data comes from a different table, and has no relation. How can I accomplish my desired result set?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Union` in between your Select queries .Example `Select col1,4 from TableA union Select col2 ,5 from Tableb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Daily and Death Counts
select * from (
    select
        SUM(CASE WHEN location != '[OUT]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Daily',
        SUM(CASE WHEN death = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Deaths'
    from
        patient_data
) tmp unpivot (Number for Type in ([Daily], [Deaths])) t

union all

-- In-House Tasks
select * from (
    select 
        SUM(CASE WHEN cat_id = 72 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'In-House EKG',
        SUM(CASE WHEN cat_id = 73 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'In-House XRay'
    from
        organizer_tasks
) tmp unpivot (Number for Type in ([In-House EKG], [In-House XRay])) t

union all

-- Suicidal Patients
select 'Suicidal Inmates',
    count(distinct(pid))
from 
    problems pr 
        inner join problem_list pl on pl.id = pr.problem_list_id 
where 
    pr.status = 'open'
    and pl.title like '%suicide%'

union all

-- HIV

select 'HIV',
    count(distinct(pid))
from 
    problems pr 
        inner join problem_list pl on pl.id = pr.problem_list_id 
        inner join patient_data pd on pr.pid = pd.pid
where 
    pr.status = 'open'
    and pl.title like '%hiv%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @muhmud, I've added one more sub query that has joins and is coming from a same table as my 'suicidal inmates' count. Could you include that in your answer?

Comment: Done. I've also updated it to use `pivot` where you have counts coming from the same from clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Union which is form in one Query :

```
    select
        SUM(CASE WHEN location != '[OUT]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Daily'   
    from
        patient_data    
UNION ALL
    select   
        SUM(CASE WHEN death = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Deaths'
    from
    patient_data

UNION ALL
-- In-House Tasks
    select 
        SUM(CASE WHEN cat_id = 72 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'In-House EKG'  
    from
    organizer_tasks
UNION ALL
    select
        SUM(CASE WHEN cat_id = 73 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'In-House XRay'
    from
        organizer_tasks 
UNION ALL
-- Suicidal Patients
    select 
        count(distinct(pid)) as 'Suicidal Inmates'
    from 
        problems pr 
            inner join problem_list pl on pl.id = pr.problem_list_id 
    where 
        pr.status = 'open'
        and pl.title like '%suicide%'
```